# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host :stream_socket_client

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send emails after user registration on laravel. But when i tried to send emails am getting following error. I have added all configurations in both env file and config/mail.php file.

Following is my code in controller

```
 public function storeUsers(Request $request)
    {

        $postdata = $request->all();
        $user = new User;
        $hashedRandomPassword = Hash::make('password', [
            'rounds' => 12
        ]);
       $user = new User;
       $user->name=$postdata['user_name'];
       $user->email=$postdata['email'];
       $user->password= $hashedRandomPassword;
       $user->save();
        Mail::to($postdata['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
       return back()->with('success','thanks for contacting us');
       exit(ok);
        //Mail::to($postdata['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
       // return $user;
       //return redirect('users');
    }
```

First of all i have created mail file using command `php artisan make:mail WelcomeMail`.
Following is the code in welcome mail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


class WelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        //return $this->from('xavierissac94@gmail.com')->subject('new customer registration')->view('emails.welcome');
       return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with('data',$this->user);
    }
}
```

Why am getting this errors please help me

Am getting following error

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://:0 (The requested address is not valid in its context.
 )
```

Following is code in .env file

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:l7aoKnAqgLJutkHthcdfdEFSzDKOpLqLPvTUuSpkQ/o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=directory
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=***
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername
MAIL_PASSWORD==mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='Site Test '

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Something is wrong in your `.env` file.

Comment: Can u pls tell what is wrong

Comment: I would need to see the `MAIL_*` entries in your .env file, with any sensitive information obfuscated, of course.

Comment: sure , will update now

Comment: I have added env file plese have a look on to it

Comment: Change `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` to `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`.

Comment: I have tested that too,since its not working i changed that to smtp,not only that please not that am sending from localhost

Comment: Ok, have you tried `MAIL_PORT=465` and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl`?

Comment: Yup, i have tried both ssl and tls and port numbers 465,25 etc

Comment: You may need to clear you application cache, come to think of it. Run `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache` and try with those settings again.

Comment: Happy to help! I'm compiled my comments into an answer as you requested. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this one also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161795/email-unique-validations-rules-are-not-working-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by verifying the values in your `.env` file are correct. In particular, check the following:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Anytime you make changes to the `.env` file, be sure to run

```
php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:cache
```

so the cached config is updated and not using old values!