# Email unique validations rules are not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i am working in Laravel project,i am using js validator to validate the form fileds, but if i use `unique:users` validation rule, the same is not working.  I want unique emails to be submitted. If i use this i will not be able to submit the form itself.All other validation rules are working properly.

Please help me to find out the issue

Following is the code in UserController,which i apply validation rules

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JsValidator;
use Validator;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Mail\WelcomeMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use DB;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Libraries\GlobalHelpers;
use App\Libraries\ImageHelpers;
use Auth;
use Response;


class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $userValidationRules = [
        'user_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    ];
 public function addUsers()
    {
        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->userValidationRules,[],[],'#addusers');
        return view('user.add')->with(['validator' => $validator]);
    }
}
```

Following is the code in view file

```
@extends('user.layout.app')

@section('content')
    <script src="{{ url('js/user/location.js') }}"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid add-location">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <form method="post"  action="{{ route('storeUsers') }}" name="addusers" id="addusers" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title"> Add Users </h4>
                        </div>
                        @if(!empty($errors->all()))
                            <div class="row"> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger"> <span>{{ $error }}</span> </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Full Name
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input id="user_name" name="user_name" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="User Name">
                                        @if ($errors->has('user_name')) <span class="help-block"> {{ $errors->first('user_name') }} </span> @endif </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email">
                                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>

</div>
                            <div class="row">


                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-action">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Submit</button>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-fill">Cancel</a> </div>
                                </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! $validator !!}
@endsection
```

What is the issue,why unique validation is not working?

Comment: 'email' =>'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email',

Comment: No,its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While submitting storeage you also need to pass validation rules,then only it will check

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $userValidationRules = [
        'user_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
    ];
```

unique:table,column
according 
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique